# Fantasy novel about an advertising executive in a different, magical world

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember the author or title of this book. The main character however is an advertising executive who ends up in a different world.

Its main identifying feature of magic there from what I recall was that magic is performed through words and intent - but each combination of words with intent can only be used once. Once a phrase had been used, it could never be used to repeat that magic. As such, the main character could use magic in ways even the magic users of the world could not with his ingenious ways to describe a specific item he needed at a particular time.

The novel is at least 20 years old, possibly older.

Comment: Sounds like the Adept series.

Comment: You're not talking about Piers Anthony's Phaze Adept series? It's not those.

Comment: I know it's not it, but the description reminds me a little of Jerry Jay Carroll's [*Top Dog.*](http://www.amazon.com/Top-Dog-Jerry-Jay-Carroll/dp/0441005136)

Comment: Based on the title it almost sounds like the Kingdom of Landover Series...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [**Moon Dreams**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1416734.Moon_Dreams) by Brad Strickland.

> *Jeremy Sebastian Moon is transported far from Earth where his dreams and job in advertising provide comfort but not much happiness, a world where fantasy is reality. This new magical world presents to Jeremy his double, a dangerous wizard who wants him to take his place and stand before the Council of Mages. Jeremy's mission before he returns home is to help the Mages battle the Evil in Thaumia. He encounters a beautiful thief, an enchantress and Nul, along his journey, but will his newfound powers take him back to earth?*

[image]

Comment: You've actually helped me answer a [question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81561/childrens-story-boy-must-rescue-his-sister-from-multi-limbed-shadow-creatures) I asked 6 months ago... The title Moon Dreams jogged my memory. The book I was trying to remember was called [Moondream](http://www.amazon.com/Moondream-Victor-Osborne/dp/0688087787). That's been in the back of my mind for years!